# Why didn't God say to woman/Eve/Chava for what sin/sins she is judged?

Tags: genesis, adam, eden

In Genesis 3, we read that when God gave the judgement, HE said to the serpent and Adam in a manner such as "**because you did such and such, so it shall be……"** but to the woman, He didn't call out the "BECAUSE", and went straight by speaking the consequences.

1. Why?
2. And imagine that God was to say "BECAUSE" at that moment to the woman, what would it be?

> 11 And he said, Who told thee that thou wast naked? Hast thou eaten of
> the tree, whereof I commanded thee that thou shouldest not eat? 12 And
> the man said, The woman whom thou gavest to be with me, she gave me of
> the tree, and I did eat. 13 And the LORD God said unto the woman, What
> is this that thou hast done? And the woman said, The serpent beguiled
> me, and I did eat. 14 **And the LORD God said unto the serpent,
> Because thou hast done this,** thou art cursed above all cattle, and
> above every beast of the field; upon thy belly shalt thou go, and dust
> shalt thou eat all the days of thy life: 15 And I will put enmity
> between thee and the woman, and between thy seed and her seed; it
> shall bruise thy head, and thou shalt bruise his heel. 16 Unto the
> woman he said, I will greatly multiply thy sorrow and thy conception;
> in sorrow thou shalt bring forth children; and thy desire shall be to
> thy husband, and he shall rule over thee. 17 And unto Adam he said,
> **Because thou hast hearkened unto the voice of thy wife, and hast eaten of the tree, of which I commanded thee, saying, Thou shalt not
> eat of it:** cursed is the ground for thy sake; in sorrow shalt thou
> eat of it all the days of thy life; 18 Thorns also and thistles shall
> it bring forth to thee; and thou shalt eat the herb of the field; 19
> In the sweat of thy face shalt thou eat bread, till thou return unto
> the ground; for out of it wast thou taken: for dust thou art, and unto
> dust shalt thou return.

Comment: @AdamHeeg you cannot say Eve was in ignorance of the law, she may have misunderstood or exaggerated the law but she knew that tree’s fruits were forbidden. Eve speaking *”but God said, ‘You shall not eat of the fruit of the tree that is in the midst of the garden, neither shall you touch it, lest you die.’””
‭‭Genesis‬ ‭3:3‬*

Comment: Great question in that the serpent was cursed, but neither Adam, nor Eve were specifically **cursed**, but hardships were handed out--leaving room for **hope**. The **earth** was cursed "for Adam's sake, but remember,  the woman was **newly formed**, together with her **seed**, out of the rib, or side, of man, rather than of the earth (The man never had a seed). **The Lord God** must have had something **very special** in mind  for mankind here.

Comment: @Adam Heeg Adam did inform Eve not to eat from the tree of knowledge of good and evil. 2¶And the woman said unto the serpent, We may eat of the fruit of the trees of the garden:
3But of the fruit of the tree which is in the midst of the garden, God hath said, Ye shall not eat of it, neither shall ye touch it, lest ye die.

Comment: She isn't judged, and that seems to me to be the point.

Answer (score 2):

In Genesis 3 there is a lot of finger pointing, but all were guilty except God.  Adam blamed both God and the woman ("the woman you gave me").  Eve (חַוָּ֣ה) blamed the serpent. From the passage, the parallel statements are understood for the woman: "because you did this" (Ate from the tree I commanded Adam not to eat and he told you I did), and "because you listened to the voice of" the serpent.

Comment: Great - a simple uncomplicated and terse answer.  +1.

Comment: @Perry Webb: I see your point. From logical reasoning, one may think "because you listened to the voice of the serpent"... but not so simple. ***13¶And the LORD God said unto the woman, What is this that thou hast done? And the woman said, The serpent beguiled me, and I did eat.*** so she was deceived. So if God would say "because you listened to the serpent, I will..." that would be as if God is saying "because you were deceived by the serpent, i will..." and then it would be strange. Would any father curse his little daughter who was cheated by a villain?

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't God say to woman/Eve/Chava for what sin/sins she is judged?

Because it was spelled out just a few verses earlier.

> Genesis 3:2 The woman said to the serpent, “We may eat fruit from the trees in the garden, 3but God did say, ‘**You must not eat** fruit from the tree that is in the middle of the garden, and you must not touch it, or you will die.’ ”

According to Eve's own understanding, she was not supposed to eat.

> 6 When the woman saw that the fruit of the tree was good for food and pleasing to the eye, and also desirable for gaining wisdom, she took some and **ate it**. She also **gave** some to her husband, who was with her, and he ate it.

Yet, she ate, directly contradicting her understanding/conscience. Furthermore, she gave some to Adam, knowing it was wrong to do so.

And imagine that God was to say "BECAUSE" at that moment to the woman, what would it be?

To Eve God could have said, "Because you listened to the serpent and ate fruit from the tree about which you must not eat from it, I will make your pains in childbearing very severe; with painful labor you will give birth to children. Your desire will be for your husband, and he will rule over you.”

Comment: Because Eve had been deceived, but Adam had not been (I Timothy 2:14).  So Adam, who was supposed to be in charge, had to take the blame for both of them.

Answer (score 0):

Why?

Because of her previously demonstrated attitude of accountability.  These (Genesis 3:14-19) are God's sentences that follow His investigations (divine questions and human answers of Genesis 3:9-13), the reason for the missing "because” (ki) clause may lie in the woman's attitude as revealed by her response when confronted by God.

Summary of prior interaction: The forms of the their answers were the same but the meanings are different. The meaning of an answer depends on the question (immediate context) being answered.

i.e. "I do": if it follows the pastor's question whether to accept a person as your spouse- it means yes I want to be married to them but it it follows the frustrated spouse's question whether one wants a divorce - it means I want a divorce. Same words, different meanings.
Answers were...

Adam: "The woman you gave to me with me, she gave to me and I ate."

Eve: "The snake deceived me and I ate."

A) Using the hermeneutical principle of Charity (interpret in the best logical sense possible), Adam's answers can be heard in the best possible way as:

God: “Where are you?”

Adam: "I heard the sound of You in the garden and I was afraid, because I was naked, and I hid myself." (Genesis 3:10) A relational, not a space-oriented answer. Beautiful. Demonstrates abstract thinking.

God: “Who told you, you were naked?”

Adam: "The woman You gave to be with me." (Genesis 3:12) Otherwise, there is no need to cover up, the animals don't care about human nakedness.

God: “Have you eaten of the tree of which I commanded you not to eat?”

Adam: "She gave to me and I ate." (Genesis 3:12) To the question “have you?” which is a yes-or-no question for the singular masculine subject, a simple "I ate" would have sufficed. The addition of "she gave to me" is clearly uncalled for, and spreads blame.

B) God's question to Eve was not a first-order question as Adam's were (direct, straightforward - "Where are you","Who told you", "Have you eaten") but a second-order question (analysis, relate, implications) requiring an explanation - "What is this?" In Eve’s question, God states He already knows **that** she did it -  “you have done".

God: What is this - you have done?

Eve: "The snake deceived me and I ate." (Genesis 3:13) Here, the mention of the snake is **not** evading God’s question, but appropriately answering the query of **why** she did it. Her final phrase "and I ate" was not needed as God had already stated as a fact, "that you have done", so her reiteration of personal fault shows additional self-incrimnation.

This is why God does not need to press on Eve the "because... cursed" to pinpoint personal responsibility. She gets it. God knows it. She has expressed remorse without blaming God or Adam (who was with her silently).

God therefore continues to press Adam to be accountable for his own choice to disobey by repeating Himself in Adam's sentencing --"Because you have listened to the voice of your wife and **ate of the tree which I commanded you not to eat** - cursed is the ground for your sake."

Context: "What is this--" is an offended demand for explanation, similar to our modern "What in the world were you thinking?"

Genesis 12:18

> So Pharoah called Abram and said,'What is this you have done to me? Why did you not tell me that she was your wife?

Genesis 26:10

> Abimelech said,'What is this you have done to us? One of the people might easily have lain with your wife, and you would have brought guilt upon us.

Genesis 44:15

> Joseph said to them,'What is this thing that you have done? Did you not know that a man like me can indeed practice divination?

Answer (score 0):

The Scriptures make it clear that no one can lie in the real presence of God. Therefore, it is certain that Adam did not lie to God. When God gave the command to Adam in Genesis 2:16-17 not to eat from the Tree of the Knowledge of Good and Evil, Eve had not yet been created (Genesis 2:21-22). The Scriptures do not detail how Eve received the command, whether through Adam or directly from God. However, Eve makes several errors by allowing the cunning Serpent to engage her in a theological discussion about God's command.

Genesis 3:3 presents God's words to Adam:

> a) "But of the fruit of the tree which is in the midst of the garden, God said, 'You shall not eat it'" (the tree in the middle of the garden being the Tree of Life, as seen in Genesis 2:9)

> b) "nor shall you touch it, lest you die" (God did not mention this in Genesis 2:16-17).

After Eve is completely deceived regarding God's command, the Serpent uses the same phrase spoken to Adam but with a negation particle to further confuse Eve: "You will not surely die." Comparing Genesis 3:3 with Genesis 2:17 reveals that Eve was deceived by the Serpent. This is also confirmed in the New Testament Scriptures, as indicated in 2 Corinthians 11 and 1 Timothy 2:14.

Eve, having been deceived by the Serpent, encounters an unspecified tree in Genesis 3:6 that "was good for food, pleasant to the eyes, and desirable to make one wise." Without any conscience burden, Eve eats the fruit. It is not reported whether Adam was near the tree, only that he received the fruit from Eve, who is now in the condition of knowing good and evil, akin to the gods (Genesis 3:22).

Thus, as mentioned at the beginning of this article, no creature can lie before the Creator, and therefore, the entire account of Genesis 3:11-14 is true. In Genesis 3:13, Eve admits, "The serpent deceived me, and I ate." Indeed, the Serpent, with cunning, altered the position of the trees in Eve's mind regarding God's command. Adam's error was listening to the voice of a deceived and divinized Eve, manipulated by the cunning of the Serpent regarding the forbidden fruit, thereby disregarding the order received from God.

Comment: "The Scriptures make it clear that no one can lie in the real presence of God." How so? Please edit to explain in detail.